# Router doesn't pass internet through ethernet

Tags: networking, router, internet, ethernet

I have my internet providers modem/router downstairs. Ethernet cable to a separate router upstairs.

I have an "internet" port on the upstairs router, but when I plug in the ethernet cable from the main router into it, it doesn't pass the internet through the other ethernet ports on it.

When I plug the main ethernet cable into port 1 instead of the one labeled "internet", it does pass internet to all the ethernet ports.

The way I see it, the "internet" port is the "in" and the other 4 ports are "out". Why does it work by using only the "out" ports? I'm probably misunderstanding something, but I would like to understand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Internet port is the WAN (outside) port and your upstairs router is not outside (external).

The other ports (1 to 4) are LAN (inside) ports. So you plugged in to an inside port and got Internet.

That is working the way it is supposed to. There is not really a concept on "in" and "out"

Also, on this router upstairs, you should log in, look at the LAN settings and turn DHCP OFF so that you only have one DHCP server. That is a good thing to do.